# How to properly represent inheritance in dual hierarchy?

Tags: c#, oop

Suppose we have two inheritance hierarchies which corelate:

```
Car -> SportsCar -> SuperCar
```

and

```
Engine -> TurboEngine -> FormulaOneEngine
```

The Car has Engine. SportsCar has TurboEngine and SuperCar has FormulaOneEngine. The question is how to properly represent this in C#. Suppose we do:

```
class Car {
  Engine Engine;
  int HeadLamps;
}
class SportsCar: Car {
  TurboEngine TurboEngine;
  int Ailerons;
}
class SuperCar: SportsCar {
  FormulaOneEngine FormulaOneEngine;
  int FlyingSaucers;
}
```

This solves the problem, but then it looks, well, ugly! For example SuperCar has now three members which would usually point to the same instance (even worse if they don't!) and also it looks unnecessary. With 4, 5 or more levels deep hierarchies this will look really ugly:

```
SuperCar.Engine
SuperCar.SportsEngine
SuperCar.FormulaOneEngine
```

Ideally all types of Car should have only a single member, called Engine, but it should be of different type, depending on the car:

```
Car.Engine
SportsCar.Engine //of type TurboEngine
SuperCar.Engine //of type FormulaOneEngine
```

Also, this should support polymorphism, so I can make

```
List<Car> x = ...
x.Add(myCar);
x.Add(mySportsCar);
x.Add(mySuperCar);
foreach(Car c in x)
{
  x.Engine ...
}
```

so using "new" members is out. I also want to be able to call directly specific methods for each engine type:

```
class Engine { int Capacity; }
class TurboEngine: Engine { int TurboCharger; }
class FormulaOneEngine: TurboEngine { int JetFuel; }

myCar.Engine.Capacity = ....
mySportsCar.Engine.TurboCharger = ...
mySuperCar.Engine.JetFuel = ...
```

Also I shall be able to use the normal inheritance goodies:

```
myCar.HeadLamps = ...
mySportsCar.HeadLamps = ....
mySportsCar.Ailerons = ....
mySuperCar.HeadLamps = ...
mySuperCar.Ailerons = ....
mySuperCar.FlyingSaucers = ....
```

Any ideas how to refactor this to serve the purpose and also look pretty? The actual code might use chains of inheritance of 4, 5 or even more levels. Am I missing something obvious or maybe some trick?

Answer (score 6):

This is a classic generic case:

**EDITED** One more time - still the same concept, but the inheritance chain is fully there. You have to have hiding properties (`new`) in order to do what you need, but since you're implementing the `ICar` interface, you still get the base property for when you have a mixed collection. I think this is the best you're going to be able to do.

```
public interface ICar
{
    IEngine Engine { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseCar<T>
    : ICar
    where T : IEngine
{
    public T Engine { get; set; }
    IEngine ICar.Engine { get { return Engine; } set { Engine = (T)value; } }
}

public class Car : BaseCar<Engine>, ICar { }

public class SportsCar : Car, ICar
{
    IEngine ICar.Engine
    {
        get { return Engine; }
        set { Engine = (TurboEngine)value; }
    }

    public new TurboEngine Engine
    {
        get { return (TurboEngine)base.Engine; }
        set { base.Engine = value; }
    }
}
public interface ISportsCar<T> : ICar where T : TurboEngine { }

public class SuperCar : SportsCar, ISportsCar<FormulaOneEngine>
{
    public new FormulaOneEngine Engine
    {
        get { return (FormulaOneEngine)base.Engine; }
        set { base.Engine = value; }
    }
}

public interface IEngine { }
public class Engine : IEngine { }
public class TurboEngine : Engine { }
public class FormulaOneEngine : TurboEngine { }
```

You can now do:

```
var cars = new List<ICar>();
cars.Add(new Car());
cars.Add(new SuperCar());
cars.Add(new SportsCar());
```

Just keep in mind that the `Engine` property will be of the `IEngine` interface type in this context, which means you won't have access to the unique properties of each class, and you could potentially hit runtime exceptions if you attempt to assign the wrong object to that property. However, if you say:

```
var mySportsCar = new SportsCar();
mySportsCar.Engine // this will be strongly typed as TurboEngine
```

Comment: It won't support different properties for different engines.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I added more since you posted this, so hopefully it's clearer. The properties for the engines will be there as long as the car's variable type is strong (i.e. `TurboEngine`'s properties will be there if the car's variable is `SportsCar`, but not if it's `ICar`).

Comment: Well, but now SporsCar is not descending from Car and SuperCar is not descending from SportsCar like I need. I only mentioned it, but did not put it in the examples, sorry. Still I need it, because I have other properties, beside Engine.

Comment: Ok, got one more edit in, and I think it's now going to get you all the way. Still the same concept as before, just organized slightly different in order to keep the inheritance all the way.

Answer (score 1):

You are out on dangerous grounds by doing that. First of all you are creating tight coupling between a specific car type and it's engine. Inheritance isn't really required then, or the engine doesn't at least have to exist in the base class.

There is a principal called "[Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)" which says that you should not expose child objects, but instead control the behavior in the root object. For instance use `Car.Start()` instead of `Car.Engine.Start()`. Otherwise the root object will loose control over it's own behavior.

So if you start to respect the Law of Demeter principle you won't have problems with having to expose the correct engine type as it's up to each car type to do that.

imho your hierarchy is a perfect candidate for the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). That is, you have a special class which only purpose is to construct your complex objects (cars). Read more about it in wikipedia. That article even have a Car builder ;)

Comment: I agree for law of demeter, but here we fall victims of the simplicity of the example (for forum it should be simple). In the real world, it is not child, it is the opposite. It is Object.Container and then TabularObject.TabularContainer and then UpdatableTabularObject.UpdatableTabularContainer, where each descendant is having more and more members. I am starting to feel that this is too deep to be discussed in a forum thread...

Answer (score 0):

You can think also about:

```
class Car {
  Engine Engine;
}
class SportsCar: Car {

  SportsCar() {
     Engine = new TurboEngine();
  }

}
class SuperCar: SportsCar {
   SuperCar() {
     Engine = new FormulaOnEngine();
  }
}
```

So you always refer to the same Engine in base class, but its *real* type is identified by *concrete* car type.

`Engine` will have `virtual` members that describe engine properties like :

- hours power
- consume
- etc..

which is overriden with appropriate values in `TurboEngine` and `FormulaOnEngine`.